# Do we have a term for knowing-oneself?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In many psychological, religious, and ethical theories it's been suggested that you **know yourself**, through contemplation, cognition, etc.

It's like trying to recognize **who you really are deep inside**, and **why you do what you do**, stuff like that.

But do we have a name for this **knowing yourself**?

Update: I'm searching for a universally recognized name, and to clarify even more, if **theology** means knowing God, I'm searching for something like **you ology**, or to know yourself.

Comment: "Self knowledge" I think captures this best.

Comment: Nice word selection @PieterGeerkens, but I'm searching for a single word, rather than a compound word. Thank you. :)

Comment: "Self aware" is even better, but still a compound word.

Comment: Why does it *have to* be one word? Could you explain?

Comment: Yeah, sure. I think a **compound word** means that you explain something, while **one word** means that, that thing has a name, which might not be descriptive.

Comment: For example, consider the word **snow**. We might also call it **falling ice** or **iced rain** or anything similar. Did I convey what I mean? If it has one word, then it's something globally recognized, but if it's a compound word, it's not.

Comment: Not exactly true, very often compound words mute over time and then become single-words. If a compound word communicates your idea, thought, and message, then it has done its job. Compound words are fixed, e.g "post office"  *toothbrush* used to be "tooth brush". "self awareness" is almost a unit. It has its own, unique meaning

Comment: Yes, I agree. The purpose of language is **to communicate**. So, based on that argument, I can use anything that helps me make people understand what I mean. However, as soon as we accept this, we end up with literally thousands of compound words which can be used to express one's idea. Isn't it like that?

Comment: I understood. I guess it's better if I say I'm searching for a globally recognized **term**, whether it's a single word, or a compound word. I just want it to be something that I can find in somewhere like wikipedia.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, the link you sent is not what I'm searching for. **Self-awareness* seems to be psychological ability to distinguish yourself from, say, your house :D

Comment: What I'm after, is a deep understanding of one's character, just the way one knows other people.

Comment: Philosophy beta: http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Kris The OP's question is on lexis, terminology, and nomenclature. His question is not philosophical. He can ask any future questions to that group at a later date. :)

Comment: There's definitely a term for knowing yourself biblically.  

Answer (score 4):

*[Satori](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/satori#Noun)* refers to “A sudden inexpressible feeling of inner understanding or enlightenment”.  While *feeling of* such understanding obviously may be different from *having* it, satori often refers to the latter.

Note, *[enlightenment](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/enlightenment#Noun)* itself is a consequence of “achieving clarity of perception, reason and knowledge”.  Also see *[epiphany](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/epiphany#Noun)*,  “An illuminating realization or discovery, often resulting in a personal feeling of elation, awe, or wonder”.

Comment: Nice choices. They seem to not be made for *self-awareness* though.  +1

Comment: [Enlightenment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enlightenment_%28spiritual%29)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/autology), the word you are looking for is **autology**. I would read it as "the study of one's self" as I would read **theology** as the study of God.

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to be looking for a name for the process of "knowing oneself through contemplation etc.", there are a few terms that may fit the bill.

1. Self-realisation (religious/spiritual term)

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-realization

1. Self-actualisation (psychological term)

> to realize fully one's potential

1. Individuation (psychological term)

> the act or process of individuating: as a (1) : the development of
>   the individual from the universal (2) : the determination of the
>   individual in the general

Answer (score 1):

"*[Nosce te ipsum](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nosce%20te%20ipsum)*" is a saying which has been thrown around quite a bit; though it's not necessarily a term, it's an aphorism, so if you're looking for a word which captures the essence of "knowing thyself", this may not be it, but it might be helpful to know that it (g**nosce**re) is the root of "cognisance (cognizance)", according to [Dictionary.com](https://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cognizance) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Greek_and_Latin_roots_in_English).

It was more widely used in the 1820-1840's than it is now though, according to Google's [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nosce%20te%20ipsum&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnosce%20te%20ipsum%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cnosce%20te%20ipsum%3B%2Cc1) viewer.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe finding who you are by exa examining the way we do things in life and choices we make the best definition for a single or plural to word answer would be a "moral inventory"

Answer (score 0):

[**Psychology**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychology)

Emphasis mine:

> Psychology is an academic and **applied discipline** that involves the
> scientific study of mental functions and behaviors. Psychology has the
> immediate goal of **understanding** individuals and groups by both
> establishing general principles and researching specific cases,...
>
> Etymology
>
> The word psychology literally means, "**study of the soul**" (ψυχή,
> psukhē, meaning "breath", "spirit", or "soul"; and -λογος -logos,
> translated as "study of" or "research". The Latin word *psychologia*
> was first used by the Croatian humanist and Latinist Marko Marulić in
> his book, *Psichiologia de ratione animae humanae* in the late 15th
> century or early 16th century.

Related to the study of "self" and to the eternal question "Who am I?

**Self-concept**
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-concept

Comment: New and nice look. Self-realization = psychology. Can we say that?

Comment: I'm not an expert. I don't have the confidence to confirm or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could be said to be [cognizant](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cognizant)

Comment: Cognizant isn't specifically related to self knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for **circumspectology**. Based on circumspective - looking around carefully, or there abouts.

Answer (score 0):

**Introspection** is the observation or examination of one's own mental and emotional state, mental processes, etc. It is the act of looking within oneself or the tendency or disposition to do this.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introspection):

> Introspection is the examination of one's own conscious thoughts and
>   feelings. In psychology the process of introspection relies
>   exclusively on observation of one's mental state, while in a spiritual
>   context it may refer to the examination of one's soul. Introspection
>   is closely related to human self-reflection and is contrasted with
>   external observation.
>
> Introspection generally provides a privileged access to our own mental
>   states, not mediated by other sources of knowledge, so that
>   individual experience of the mind is unique. Introspection can
>   determine any number of mental states including: sensory, bodily,
>   cognitive, emotional and so forth.

Answer (score -4):

How about *sibiology*? The root *sibi* and the study seem to fit.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. We value answers which justify what they suggest (Where does *sibi* come from?) and also answers which are written in sentences, with capital letters and punctuation.